# PHP shell_exec will not execute ssh

Tags: php

I am running PHP and Apache. My program is as follows:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("ssh");
?>
```

It works from the command line as `php script.php` but when visiting the web browser `127.0.0.1/script.php` it returns an empty result.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

**Edit 1:**
I tried running ssh as the www-data user through command line. This worked fine.

**Edit 2:** 
I tried running sshpass instead of ssh (same location, same permissions) and it works but ssh does not.

Comment: Probably apache/web user doesn't have permissions to execute `ssh`. I've used https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php for this before

Comment: Added www-data user to sudoers for ```/usr/bin/ssh``` and tested with ```sudo ssh```. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned in [kamermans's note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#78506), the help message of ssh is output to the stderr stream, so try

`echo shell_exec('ssh 2>&1');`